# how to layer shapes on top of text in MS Publisher

Tags: microsoft-publisher

I need to draw a shape around some text in MS Publisher 2010. For example, draw a box around "Jan 1" in a long text box or around the "1" on the calendar in January. The problem is when I place the shape on top of the text, Publisher moves my text around the shape. Can anyone tell me how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape, and from the context (right-click) menu, select Format Autoshape.  Select the Layout tab on the dialog that appears and in the 'Wrapping Style' section, select None.

[image]